# Firebase Usage data is only provided for the current month and is not available when viewing historical periods

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I paid X Dollars last month for Firebase services. As a Firebase user, I would like to see a detailed breakdown of my usage last period (or older periods) for each service. In other words, for instance, how many read counts happened on Firestore in each of the previous periods.

Where can get such data?

I tried to go under Usage and billing but it only shows details for the current period.

When I tried to see for last period, I get the message:

`Usage data is only provided for the current month and is not available when viewing historical periods.`

I also tried to go under Cloud Firestore > Usage, but it only shows usage data for the last 30 days, but not for the previous period. So If today is the 15th of Feb, it will show me between 15th of Jan to 15th of Feb, not 1st of Jan to 1st of Feb

Answer (score 0):

The Usage and billing page in the Firebase Console is still in Beta stage as you can see in the following image.
[image]

Currently you can see the usage data for all the Firebase products in the Usage and billing page for the current month only. There is no option to see the usage data for the earlier periods.

For individual products in the usage tab you can see the usage details maximum upto last 30 days. For example for Firestore Database you will get to see the following.
[image]

If you want to have the feature added in the Firebase console to view the usage data for the earlier months you can [raise a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) with the free Firebase Support Team.